# Can I boot an Acer Power S260 from a USB flash drive?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, usb-flash-drive

I have an Acer Power S260 which I am trying to boot from a USB flash drive to install a Linux variant.

There are options in the BIOS for booting from USB-FDD, USB-ZIP, and USB-CDROM, but not from USB-HDD or USB. I've tried all of the possibilities without success.

I've also looked for an option to switch from UEFI to legacy, but can't find that anywhere in the BIOS.

Is it possible to boot an S260 from a USB flash drive? If so, how?

-- Details --

The S260 was apparently built in 2005. It has 0.5 GB of memory and is running Windows XP. I want to convert it to Neverware's CloudReady, a version of Linux derived from Chromium. CloudReady's installer is on a USB flash drive.

When I boot into XP, the OS can see the flash drive, but says it's not formatted. I believe this is what it should see since the installer should have reformatted the flash drive so it's no longer NTFS.